# update table set Status="Closed " where requestId IN (36455, 35156, 35109, 32481, 32478 )

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I would like to update Status= Closed for multiple **requests**  at once

Comment: What error you have? It will be better if we have the table structure too.

Comment: my stakes are on the `"double quotes"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below:

```
update table 
set Status='"Closed"' --just added single quotes.
where requestId IN (36455, 35156, 35109, 32481, 32478 );
```

O/p will be : row updated as "Closed" with double quotes. And if your requirement is not to get double quotes then simply replace it with sigle quotes. Check below;

```
update table 
    set Status='Closed' --removed double quotes.
    where requestId IN (36455, 35156, 35109, 32481, 32478 );
```

o/p will be : Status is set to  Closed (No quotes around close).